# how to analyze memory usage in Windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to analyze memory usage in Windows phone. I want to get the memory details about **Internal Memory**, **RAM**. In that I want to analyze **Total memory, Used memory, Free memory**.

I was successful to find the **phone memory Free space and Total RAM Size** but I failed to find used RAM, Free RAM, Used Phone memory, Total space in phone memory.  Is there any way to find this? Any example?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check memory usgae real-time, check out the [Coding4Fun toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) MemoryCounter. You can add the counter to any page via code or xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
   <funtoolkit:MemoryCounter/>
</Grid>
```

The MemoryCounter control will display memory stats as you navigate your app. (Note: You'll want to add it to any page that you want to profile)

If you want to get a full report of memory usage then you should use the memory profiler built into Visual Studio. From the Debug menu select Start Windows Phone Application Analysis. This will open a window in which you can pick if you want to profile memory or performance.

You can read more about the profiler [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202934%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

go to storage sense -> tap on 'Phone' will list apps residing on internal memory.

Tap on SD card -> will list other apps.